# How to number unique customer ID's sequentially in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Please see the picture below. I would like to enter a formula to automatically enter the transaction number which is sequential and 1/3/2008 is the first transaction. As you can see, each client may order 1-10 items in each transaction (M. Deveraux has 4 items) but as long as its a purchase by the same customer on the same day, its the same transaction. Everything is ordered by date and the clients that order more than 1 item per transaction are always sequentially ordered. Please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the top-left cell in the image above is cell `A1` ...

1. Leave the first transaction number as 1 in cell `B2`.
2. Enter the following formula in cell `B3`: `=IF(AND(D3=D2,E3=E2),B2,B2+1)`.
3. Copy that formula down through the rest of your sheet.
4. (If this answer works for you, mark it as correct; I notice in your profile that you've never done so previously.)